# In Tensorflow, what is the best way to add weight decay to a model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to add weight decay (aka L2 regularization) to my model. I'm seeing two ways to do this but not sure which one is correct.

Defined in the keras layers as a `kernel_regularizer`:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1.0 / 255),
        hub.KerasLayer(HUB_URL, trainable=False),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            num_classes,
            activation="softmax",
            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
        ),
    ]
)
```

Defined in the loss function as `weight_decay`:

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay)
```

Where should I set the weight decay. Should it be in both?

Comment: Until now, use callback. (Or, use override the train step function.)

Comment: You can define the `weight_decay` argument inside [Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam) optimizer(). [L2 regularizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L2) does not have weight_decay parameter and is used for penality regularizer.